# What SEO software do you recommend?

Tags: seo, software

I'm investigating SEO software to buy, do you have any recommendations?

I would like to have SEO software that gives me useful information about my site's content based on keywords and also gives me a list of broken links, title and description recommendations based on the latest Google and other major search engine algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I nether support or discourage the use of SEO Powersuite - but it might be cheaper than forking out that amount of money every month for web based SEO.

http://www.link-assistant.com/

(They do seem to update there software on a regular basis as well)

Answer (score 1):

Desktop software tends to go out of date pretty quick, so i'd recommend web-based applications like [Raven Tools](http://raventools.com/seo-tools/) and [SEOMoz Tools](http://www.seomoz.org/tools).

Comment: Whats your opinion about link-assistant?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get whole information regarding your website here : http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/

Comment: Interesting definition of "whole"

Answer (score 0):

I have used [A1 website analyzer](http://www.microsystools.com/products/website-analyzer/) in the past, and it is a fairly enhanced robot that can crawl your website and unearth a whole bunch of problems like duplicate content, broken links and whatnot. It's not free, but has a free evaluation so you can take it for a spin.